# MobileVlcKit compiling Failed

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, vlc, broadcast, libvlc

Hi i am trying to use MobileVLCKit.For that i am using cocoapads like below
pod 'MobileVLCKit'

```
pod 'MobileVLCKit'
```

then i compile my project it is showing plenty of errors below is my error Log

```
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

"std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::find(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  TagLib::String::find(TagLib::String const&, int) const in MobileVLCKit(tstring.cpp.o)
  TagLib::String::split(TagLib::String const&) const in MobileVLCKit(tstring.cpp.o)

  dash::mpd::BasicCMParser::parseCommonAttributesElements(dash::xml::Node*, dash::mpd::CommonAttributesElements*, dash::mpd::CommonAttributesElements*) const in MobileVLCKit(libdash_plugin_la-BasicCMParser.o)
```

I tried with architecture x86_64 but still showing lot of errors. I don't know how to clear these errors.so can any body please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current stable version of MobileVLCKit (2.2.2) available through Cocoapods requires the libstdc++ runtime environment for iOS 6.1 to provide backward compatibility. To resolve the errors, you need to set the deployment version of the target linking MobileVLCKit to iOS 6.1.

The next major version of MobileVLCKit (3.0.0) will require iOS 7 and use the modern libc++, so the issue will no longer occur. Alternatively, use the pod "MobileVLCKit-prod" (version 2.7.2), which is the production release we use ourselves to ship VLC-iOS.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the Bitrate of playing video please help me

Comment: Thanks, I've added "MobileVLCKit-prod" instead of "MobileVLCKit" and now i can compile and run without problems. But how do I integrate the player into a view controller? There's no option to import "MobileVLCKit" or similar.

Comment: Got it. In case someone stumbles upon this post as well: a bridging header needs to be added including `#import "MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h"`.

Comment: @SebastianGreifeneder how did you added the MobileVLCKit-prod" using cocoapods.

Comment: @Bittoo just add `pod "MobileVLCKit-prod"` to your Podfile

Comment: @feepk, the pod "MobileVLCKit-prod" doesn't work. How can I use version 3.0.0 ?

Comment: Version 3.0.0 is not released yet. To deploy the latest code, use “MobileVLCKit-unstable” in 3.0.0a33.